# Swift compiler crashes on where clause

Tags: generics, swift, crash

On the weekend I started playing around with Swift. I am trying to build a calculator like application. Therefore I want to model a tree of expressions.

The whole swift compiler suite/xcode seems to be still very unstable. I keeps crashing every few minutes.
This is why I would like to know if my code is wrong or if it is just the compiler being buggy.

---

Those two protocols are compiling fine

```
protocol BinaryOperator {
    typealias LeftType
    typealias RightType
    typealias ResultType

    func apply(left: LeftType, right: RightType) -> ResultType
}

protocol UnaryOperator {
    typealias SourceType
    typealias ResultType

    func apply(SourceType) -> ResultType
}
```

But adding the following class the compiler crashes with a segmentation fault on the first line of the class. I suspect it is caused by the where clause because if I remove it, the compiler is not crashing anymore but it still does not compile due to the type mismatches.

```
class BinaryExpression<O:BinaryOperator, L:Expression, R:Expression
where L.ResultType==O.LeftType, R.ResultType==O.RightType> : Expression {

    typealias ResultType = O.ResultType

    let op : O
    let lhs : L
    let rhs : R

    init(op o : O, left : L, right: R) {
        op = o
        lhs = left
        rhs = right
    }

    func eval() -> ResultType {
        let left : O.LeftType = lhs.eval()
        let right : O.RightType = rhs.eval()

        return op.apply(left, right: right)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...
The problem was the order of the Types at the equality operator in the where clause.

Compare(crashing)

```
class BinaryExpression
<O:BinaryOperator, L:Expression, R:Expression 
where L.ResultType==O.LeftType, R.ResultType==O.RightType> {}
```

with(working)

```
class BinaryExpression
<O:BinaryOperator, L:Expression, R:Expression 
where O.LeftType==L.ResultType, O.RightType==R.ResultType> {}
```